Counting RMS value of trapezium shape signal
I have an example here how to count RMS voltage value of trapezium shape signal:

Signal parameters:
H1=11;
L1=9;
C1=0;
tи1=0,15∙T
And given formula:

My question related to RMS formula: we have a sum of 3 values: H1^2 + L1^2 + H1*L1. Why H1 and L1 are multiplied (as a third value)?

In the PDF file on the page, you have a full derivation. To find RMS value we need to find the area of a square of the waveform. So we are getting --> 9^2 = 81 and 11^2 = 121. Thus RMS = Sqrt(81* 0.15 + ((121 - 81) * 0.15)/2) ≈ 3.89

Yes, but my question was about H1*L1 part..

But this result comes directly from calculating the definite integral.  So what the answer do you expect to see?
